# View not getting resolved in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

View is not getting resolved after controller is hit . The @RequestMapping works fine but the jsp is not getting resolved.

Below is the application.properties file

```
server.servlet-path=/*
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String getIndexPage() {
    System.out.println("Coming to controller");
    return "landing"
```

}

I am hitting the url:http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/index to which I am getting blank page and the below error:

```
16:01:38,447 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Cannot forward to error page for request [/index] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Comment: Appears you are using Spring Boot. Last time I used JSP, you had to use a WAR file not JAR.

Comment: I am creating a deployable war. And I am using jboss as my application server.

Comment: @Chandan Did you had a chance to solve your problem? Having the same now right now.

Comment: @javadev I too had the same problem , few answers suggested to convert it as war if you are using jsp but even after if you are getting error , then define view resolver using WebMvcConfigurationSupport , you will surely get